# Where did Python wheel files get their name?

Tags: python, pip, python-wheel

I've read the PEP (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0427/) about wheels and understand WHAT they are, I just don't understand why they're called wheels. I find it a bit confusing, since wheel the group with sudo privileges widely used in nix systems

Comment: Oh, interesting. Egg made sense because of the containment + Monty Python reference (like spam and eggs instead of foo and bar for example variables). Wheel... What's the reference or how the name relates to other things in Python?